# What is the difference between safeTransferFrom() and transferFrom() functions in openzapplin ERC721 token contract?

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin, transferfrom

I feel there is no need to have safeTransferFrom ,  the basic tasks can be doable with transferFrom(). Could you please let me know whether can I go ahead with removing safeTransferFrom() function from manually copied code from openzapplin? is there any risk to do the same?

Answer (score 5):

The `safeTransferFrom` function is used to check if the address receiving the token is an ERC-721 receiver or not. The goal is to ensure that your NFT does not get locked up in an address from which you can never retrieve it. Try and read the documentation for the [`ERC721TokenReceiver`](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721).

Comment: Official documentation for `ERC721TokenReceiver` is at https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721